# When to use --version option in helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm trying to understand when and how `--version` option in  `helm upgrade` works. In the [docs](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/helm/#options-43) it says:

> --version string   Specify the exact chart version to use. If this is not specified, the latest version is used

Lets say I have installed my app.

```bash
helm install my-app-rls my-app-1.0.0.tgz
```

Now, If I update my chart and create another package `my-app-1.0.1.tgz` I can upgrade by

```bash
helm upgrade my-app-rls my-app-1.0.1.tgz
```

`Chart.yaml` of `my-app-1.0.1.tgz` already contains a version. When does `--version` need to be used? What is the use case of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `--version` when pulling a chart from a chart repository. For example:

```
helm upgrade app chart_name \
  --version 1.0.0 \
  --repo https://chart.repo.example.com \
  --install --values ./values.yml
```

This says to find and use version 1.0.0 found at the url defined by `--repo`